# Remove last character from lines if it matches with bash/awk

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

I have a load of csv files, but they are not clean.

They use "|" as a seperator. Some of the files have a trailing "|" after line one, meaning there is N columns in line 1, and N+1 in line 2+.

I want to cycle through the files and remove the trailing separator on lines that have it.

What is the best way to do this for a single file using the shell with awk or a similar tool?

Input csv:

```
|some|data|here
|some|more|data|
|even|more|data|
```

Output:

```
|some|data|here
|some|more|data
|even|more|data
```

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in your question to avoid close votes on your question, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `sed` inplace replacement:

```
sed -i 's/|$//' test.txt
```

---

- `|$` - matches `|` at the end of the line `$`

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '/\|$/{
  $0=substr($0,1,length($0)-1)
}
1
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this out too :

```
perl -pe 's/\|$//' test.txt
```

Output

```
|some|data|here
|some|more|data
|even|more|data
```

Comment: Please explain why are using `perl` which is not one of tags used, as opposed to `awk` and `sed`

Comment: I did this because most people are unaware of the excellent features that Perl has.

Answer (score 2):

> there is N columns in line 1, and N+1 in line 2+.

If you know N apriori you might just set `NF` to that value in GNU `AWK`, in case of your data it is 4 (observe there 1st column is always empty), if `file.txt` content is

```
|some|data|here
|some|more|data|
|even|more|data|
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}NF=4' file.txt
```

output

```
|some|data|here
|some|more|data
|even|more|data
```

Explanation: I set both field separator and output field separator to pipe character in `BEGIN`'s action, then set number of field to 4, which lead to deletion of further fields. If you want to know more about `FS` or `OFS` or `NF` then read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '
 |some|data|here
 |some|more|data|
 |even|more|data|' |
```

---

```
gawk \/\/ RS='[|]?\r?\n' # precisely trim off 1 trailing pipe
mawk  $$  RS='[\r|]*\n'  # trim off any amount of it
nawk NF=1 FS='[|]$'      # via column splitter FS instead of row-splitter RS
```

---

```
|some|data|here
|some|more|data
|even|more|data
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'sub(/\|?$/,"")' file
|some|data|here
|some|more|data
|even|more|data
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer?